# Disable minor modes like flycheck-mode and flymake-mode by default

Tags: functions

I disable the following the modes in `init.el`

```
;;flycheck-mode                                                                                                               
;;flymake-mode                                                                                                                
(flycheck-mode nil)
(flymake-mode nil)
(prettify-symbols-mode nil)
```

However, they did not work as expected.

My emacs.d excluding 'init.el` cloned from [purcell/emacs.d: An Emacs configuration bundle with batteries included](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d)

the flycheck-mode flymake-mode and prettify-symbols-mode are enabled by defautl.

The above three are of type function, why not working by passing nil to them?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49370733/324105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the modes you list are minor modes defined by `define-minor-mode`.

From the doc of `define-minor-mode`:

> When called from Lisp, the mode command toggles the mode if the
>   argument is ‘toggle’, disables the mode if the argument is a
>   non-positive integer, and enables the mode otherwise (including
>   if the argument is omitted or nil or a positive integer).

So, you enable the mode when you call it with `nil` argument. You should call it with a non-positive integer like 0 or -1,... instead.